# Chrome not starting using Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

The script works locally, but not on a server.

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true
```

Error:

```
response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux 4.9.75-29.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:84:in `new'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:84:in `create_response'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:104:in `request'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:62:in `call'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:166:in `execute'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:99:in `create_session'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:53:in `handshake'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:49:in `initialize'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `new'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `for'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in `for'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from rebooter.rb:9:in `new'
        from rebooter.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

I found few answers mentioning `--disable-dev-shm-usage`, but I don't really know how to pass it.

I tried without success:

```
Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true, disableDevShmUsage: true
```

I am not really sure what shm is, but df is showing I have 0% usage of it:

```
# df -h | grep -Ei 'shm|use%'
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                           962M     0  962M   0% /dev/shm
```

**How to modify the script to run also on a server? Why is it working locally, but not on a server?**

Comment: Try to `xvfb-run chrome` from bash and see what it says. You're probably missing dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combined with your own discovery, you can pass args like this:

```
args = %w[headless disable-gpu disable-dev-shm-usage disable-software-rasterizer no-sandbox]
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, args: args
```

`shm` is short for [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory).
About the [sandbox](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox.md).

If you are using remote chromdriver, then above simple way of passing args won't work, then:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, {url: "http://127.0.0.1:9515", chromeOptions: {args: args}}
```

`http://127.0.0.1:9515` is an example of remote chromedriver server.

Note `no-sandbox` is not recommended if you have other solution.
So it's better to fix it or change to use other browser instead.
Like `firefox` also has `headless` mode now, combined with [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) is a good option too.

Comment: Tried this way, sadly it leads to the exactly same error :(.

Comment: @menfon  Sorry it didn't help. Did you try upgrade chrome or downgrade chromedriver?

Comment: No need to apologize, you did steer me to right direction (how to actually pass arguments). I am using CentOS as well (not VPS though, ancient hw running at other room). I managed to make it running after adding a bunch of more arguments: `args = %w[headless disable-gpu disable-dev-shm-usage disable-software-rasterizer no-sandbox]`. If you update the answer, please ping me and I'll accept it ;).

Comment: @menfon  Updated :)